# How to truncate decimal points in mysql column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like this

```
Percentage
0.00
0.00
10.10
0.90
0.00
```

I want that to be like this

```
Percentage
0
0
10.10
0.90
0
```

And this is my query

```
  SELECT discount_percentage - TRUNCATE(discount_percentage, 0),    IF(discount_percentage - TRUNCATE(discount_percentage, 0) = 0.00, TRUNCATE(discount_percentage, 0), discount_percentage) AS percentage FROM `order` WHERE 1
```

And my result is:

```
      discount_percentage - TRUNCATE(discount_percentage, 0)   percentage
                                                       0.00     0.00
                                                       0.00     0.00
                                                       0.99     10.99
                                                       0.00     0.00
```

My precentage field have type as float

If 0.00 means i want like 0 also if 10.00 means 10 and 10.99 means 10.99. Please if anyone know get me out of this

Comment: whats the data type of your column percentage?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..I think this is what you are looking for..

```
select 
case when v regexp '(.)(\.00$)' then truncate(v,0) else v end as Percentage
from YourTable;
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I don't know whats the error. Even query logic also right

Comment: whats the output you are getting? can you give an example? also you have not mentioned the data type of your column percentage.

Comment: I am getting the output for 10.00 as 10.00 but i want as 10 for 12.11 i want 12.11. Is that clear for you

Answer (score -1):

SELECT percentage, SUM(CASE WHEN percentage >=0 THEN percentage ELSE 0 END) as discount_percentage FROM #test GROUP BY percentage

Its working for me, but one thing you need to check. It would be better to do GROUP BY some other column then percentage (maybe id column?)